# Laravel (MySQL) migration FK works when it's onDelete('CASCADE') but throws an error for onDelete('SET DEFAULT')

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have a migration in Laravel with a foreign key,

It works fine when I set `onDelete('CASCADE')` but throws an error for `onDelete('SET DEFAULT')`

> SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1215 Cannot add foreign key constraint (SQL: alter table `users` add constraint `users_theme_id_foreign` foreign key (`theme_id`) references `themes` (`id`) on delete SET DEFAULT on update cascade)

Themes table (this runs before the users table):

```
Schema::create('themes', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->smallIncrements('id');
    $table->string('color')->nullable();
});

// Inserting default theme
DB::table('themes')->insert([
    'id'    => 1,
    'name'  => 'Something'
]);
```

Users table (only FK and theme_id column):

```
Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
    ...
    $table->unsignedSmallInteger('theme_id')->default(1);
    ...
    $table->foreign('theme_id')->references('id')->on('themes')->onDelete('SET DEFAULT')->onUpdate('SET DEFAULT');
});
```

### Update:

As I said the users migration above fails, but weirdly as soon as I replace the Foreign Key to `CASCADE` it works just fine!

```
$table->foreign('theme_id')->references('id')->on('themes')->onDelete('CASCADE')->onUpdate('CASCADE');
```

More Info:

- Both tables are InnoDB and have the same Encoding and Collation.
- Laravel 6.15.0
- PHP v7.4.1
- MySQL v5.7.26

Comment: your theme_id should be nullable and the default set as null